# Not being able to follow links in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

When I run my scrapy web crawler it is not following the pages to scrape the data in my code.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import YellowpagesItem

class YSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yp2'
    allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=Conshohocken%2C+PA'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('a.businesss-name'):
            yield response.follow(link.attrib.get('href'), callback=self.parse_business)

    def parse_business(self, response):
        item = YellowpagesItem()
        item['name'] = response.css('h1::text').get()
        item['phone'] = response.css('p.phone::text').get()
        item['street'] = response.css('h2 > span::text').get()
        item['city_state'] = response.css('div.contact > h2.address::text').get()
        item['tags'] = ','.join([item.get() for item in response.css('p.cats > a::text')])
        item['email'] = response.css('a.email-business').attrib.get('href')
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo on your selector, it should be `a.business-name`.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('a.businesss-name'):
        yield response.follow(link.attrib.get('href'), callback=self.parse_business)
```

If you do not know already, you can test your selector and follow function on Scrapy shell, this will avoid such situations, enter in your terminal:

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=Conshohocken%2C+PA'
```

Then test the selectors like:

```
>> response.css('a.business-name')
<< 
>> response.css('a.business-name')
<< [<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self:...>,...]
>> response.follow(response.css('a.business-name::attr(href)').get())
<< <GET https://www.yellowpages.com/conshohocken-pa/mip/tony-joes-pizzeria-10728468?lid=1002028703627>
```